# Java - myVar cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

```
while (someCondition) {
    double myVar = someFunc(); // someFunc returns 41

    if (myVar > 0) {
     String precision ="##";
     DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0."+precision);
     // breakpoint set on next line
     double myVarPercentage = Double.parseDouble(df.format((myVar/50)*100));
    }
}
```

When I look at the value of myVar via eclipse it states it cannot be resolved to a variable despite someFunc() resolving to 41. The above fragment is executing inside a loop inside an instance method and there are no other variables in scope entitled 'myVar'.

Do I have to declare the double outside the loop?

Comment: when you are inspecting `myVar` where is the execution stopped? it has to be inside the `while` loop because outside it the variable does not exists

Comment: as in code comment, on last statement.

Comment: This code should compile, at least as far as `myVar` is concerned. The error should have a line reference - to which line in the posted does the error refer?

Comment: what I was asking is in which like the debugger has stopped

Comment: Can this be reduced to a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that will resolve whether this is a code or another issue pretty quickly, usually.

Comment: I can't see issue in this code may be issue in some where else

Comment: the problem most probably is the debugger is stopped outside the loop

Comment: Arun - the breakpoint line

Comment: why on earth has this been downvoted? Frustrated SO's who can't accept not being able to answer a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are debugging in eclipse. Sometimes the compiled .class is older than the .java source, and you get such an effect. Often the compiled code places the line number info in the code a bit skewed, for instance in a multi-line if-condition.

Place a breakpoint a bit before and do a single-step.

Comment: it does seem to be out of kilter as I step through, and I just built and deployed from latest code.

Comment: Clean (full build) might help. Maybe continuous compilation in the background (make an edit + save). And _the_ programmers solution: restart the thing (eclipse).

Comment: My sympathies. I am more of a NetBeans guy, so beside Servers, F3, I do not know.

Comment: Marking this as correct answer. I think eclipse debugging crashed once somehow blocking debugging connections between my host and server. Restarted my local box and debugging works again.